# In part 3.1 I cut-n-paste the php text, save it to a service.php file and NOTHING shows up when I run the file via http://mydomain/service.php

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

In this tutorial, I am using the same hosting service (bluehost) in combination with wordpress. Does anyone know why the page is showing an error message when I inout the url.

### https://codewithchris.com/iphone-app-connect-to-mysql-database/

```
<?php
 
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","dbname");
 
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
 
// This SQL statement selects ALL from the table 'Locations'
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Locations";
 
// Check if there are results
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
    // If so, then create a results array and a temporary one
    // to hold the data
    $resultArray = array();
    $tempArray = array();
 
    // Loop through each row in the result set
    while($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        // Add each row into our results array
        $tempArray = $row;
        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
    }
 
    // Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results
    echo json_encode($resultArray);
}
 
// Close connections
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

- I've added the phpmyadmin database image below

---

[image: Database in PHPADMIN]

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking there is no data in the database, Can I have a look at your database table  ??

✏️ The connection is established it does not show anything because your database is empty, Please make sure there is data available for fetch.

I have tested this code and it works there nothing wrong, I am 100% sure your database is empty or you did not change the example values.
Thanks buddy

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fV3zB.png)

[Code Written in IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1o1w.png)

[Code Result in the terminal with JSON data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4Du4.png)

Comment: Hi, do you know how I can upload an image, I am new to the site. However maybe I can explain, I  made a table in phpmyadmin. I am supposed to receive this text after the url, represented in part 3.2 of the tutorial linked. 

SELECT * FROM `Locations`


Name Address Latitude Longitude 
Apple 1 Infinite Loop Cupertino, CA 37.331741 -122.030333 
Googleplex 1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy View, CA 37.421999 -122.083954

Comment: I have checked it woking here is the Images you can have a look.
https://ibb.co/hLrVQz9
https://ibb.co/FxRk4fj

Comment: Hi, I've edited the question for the image of the database to appear, please take a look.

Comment: What is your site URL, please? Did you change this with original value  
 '$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","dbname");' ??

Comment: https://beachbumbookworm.com - This is the site url. I did change everything to the correct values I am assuming. I follow the tutorial link in full, ultimate goal is to produce mobile application. The tutorial seemed very standard.

Comment: Brother, it's working   https://pasteboard.co/JhDFEhy.png

Comment: Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) - This is the message I am now receiving. Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: I just put Beachbumbookworm.com/service.php in my google browser and it's not working. But how does it work for you, if I can't see it ? This is the exact message I keep getting: Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) - This is the message I am now receiving.

Comment: Now it shows this error ""Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"" Last time it worked I have attached screenshot you can have a look. 

Follow the article carefully it will work.

Comment: This is what I did...."Did you change this with original value '$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","myinfo","myinfo","myinfo");' ?? " and then localhost just stays the same as "localhost", is that correct ? I changed the three, including the  username, password and dbname... then I went to the url of google and typed in the site  + /service.php, I get an error message.

Comment: $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","dbname");.... was I supposed to also change "localhost" to my info in this line of code ? @AbdullahAlNorman

Comment: Yes, you need to give it an actual Host, User, Pass

Comment: Question for you, this tutorial isn't the outcome, that I will want in the end, I wanted to create a mobile application for the website you've seen (Thebeachbumbookworm). I just need a simple application, that I can book book reviews on, can you help me with how to edit the existing code for this tutorial to do that ?